# Remove a textarea from a table td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a textarea to be removed when 'x' is clicked, The x has an id which should is the same as the textarea. So if i am in row j say column 3 which has three textareas and i click the x under the textarea, the text area matching the x's id should be removed

HTML Snip

```
<style>
    table, tr, td{
        border: 1px solid black;

    }
    textarea,select{
        display:block;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <tr class="_rows">

        <td valign="middle" align="center" height="56" class="side">Assay                                 
            <input type="hidden" value="5" name="tests[]">
        </td>

        <td valign="middle" align="center">
            <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
            <textarea placeholder="Input Value" class="det methods ui-autocomplete-input" value="" name="method_3[]" cols="10" rows="1" id="1" autocomplete="off">UV</textarea> <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
            <textarea placeholder="Input Value" class="det methods ui-autocomplete-input" value="" name="method_3[]" cols="10" rows="1" id="2" autocomplete="off">Titration</textarea> <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
            <textarea placeholder="Input Value" class="det methods ui-autocomplete-input" value="" name="method_3[]" cols="10" rows="1" id="3" autocomplete="off">Titrati</textarea>        
        </td>
        <td valign="middle" align="center">
            <textarea placeholder="Input Value" class="det" value="" name="compedia_3[]" cols="10" rows="1" id="1">Manufacturer's In - House Method</textarea>  
        </td>

        <td valign="middle" align="center">
            <textarea placeholder="Input Value" class="det" value="" name="specification_3[]" cols="10" rows="1" id="1">1.9  - 2.1 mg</textarea> 
            <textarea placeholder="Input Value" class="det" value="" name="specification_3[]" cols="10" rows="1" id="2">9.5 - 10.5 mg</textarea>
        </td>
        <td valign="middle" align="center" id="addinput">

            <textarea placeholder="Input Value" class="det" value="" name="determined_3[]" cols="10" rows="1" id="1"> Chlorpheniramine  2.0 mg,(RSD=1.0%,n=6)</textarea><a data-id="1" class="rem1" href="#remove-field-1">x</a> 
            <textarea placeholder="Input Value" class="det" value="" name="determined_3[]" cols="10" rows="1" id="2"> Pseudoephedrine Hydrochloride 10.1 mg,(RSD=0.6%,n=3)</textarea><a data-id="2" class="rem1" href="#remove-field-2">x</a> 
            <textarea placeholder="Input Value" class="det" value="" name="determined_3[]" cols="10" rows="1" id="3">Ammonium Chloride 50.9 mg, (RSD=0.3%,n=3)</textarea><a data-id="3" class="rem1" href="#remove-field-3">x</a>


        </td>
        <td valign="middle" align="center" class="side">

            <select selected="selected" class="det" name="complies_3[]" id="1">
                <option value="COMPLIES">COMPLIES</option>
                <option value="COMPLIES">COMPLIES</option>
                <option value="DOES NOT COMPLY">DOES NOT COMPLY</option>
                <option value=":">SPLIT</option>
            </select>

            <select selected="selected" class="det" name="complies_3[]" id="2">
                <option value="COMPLIES">COMPLIES</option>
                <option value="COMPLIES">COMPLIES</option>
                <option value="DOES NOT COMPLY">DOES NOT COMPLY</option>
                <option value=":">SPLIT</option>
            </select>

            <select selected="selected" class="det" name="complies_3[]" id="3">
                <option value="COMPLIES">COMPLIES</option>
                <option value="COMPLIES">COMPLIES</option>
                <option value="DOES NOT COMPLY">DOES NOT COMPLY</option>
                <option value=":">SPLIT</option>
            </select>


        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery Snip

```
$(document).on('click', '.rem1', function () {
    $id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var $textarea = $(this).parent('td').find('textarea'); // up, back and down
    var id = $textarea.attr('id');
    alert($id + ' = ' + id)

    if ($id === id) {
        alert(1)
        id.fadeOut(function () {
            id.remove();
        });
    } else {
        // alert(0)
    }

});
```

The above code does not do it, any suggestions?

Comment: You should always look at the error messages in the console of your browser. The console will complain about `fadeOut`  not being a function. The `id`  is a string and is not your `$textarea`.

Comment: you shouldn't have duplicate IDs in your html

Answer (score 0):

If only you won't change the structure of the html code, I mean you will always wanted x to remove it's previous textarea and the textarea will remain in the same column with x, you can use .prev(selector) to remove the previous textarea of the clicked x

```
 $(this).prev("textarea").remove();
 $(this).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ygawqhpw/1/

Comment: The idea of the OP to use the `id` is a good idea. The `prev` will only work as long as the OP won't change the structure of its html code, so it generally would be better to use `id`, `class` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys,  Emad, that works. It did what I wanted. What if a single text area remains and it should not be removed?

Comment: @Alphy Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ygawqhpw/2/), I added the condition `if($("#addinput textarea").length > 1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Emad, That did it

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.rem1', function () {
    $id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var $textarea = $('textarea#'+$id ); 
    $textarea.fadeOut(function () {
            $textarea.remove();
    });
});
```

Once you get `id` from `data-id` there is no need of going to  searching through all the textarea. Each textarea will have its own unique id so you can directly target it with jquery. Once you have its reference you can fade out it and ultimately remove it.